# Combine [standards] and [code-standards]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, retag-request

[code-standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-standards)

- 51 questions
- 2 followers
- No tag wiki

[standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standards)

- 2,036 questions
- 51 followers
- Tag wiki

As far as I can tell, there is no need to keep [code-standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-standards), considering the content of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

[code-standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-standards) seems to be similar to [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style). [standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standards), on the other hand, is more (too?) general, covering, yes, code standards, but also other sorts of standards like language and protocol specifications. I think you’ll agree that [Is a header necessarily a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261508/is-a-header-necessarily-a-file) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345530/constructor-naming-standards are very different applications of [standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standards).

If anything, I think we should merge [code-standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-standards) into [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) and retag [standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standards) questions pertaining to coding style with [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style).